# acceder a servidor Linux Arch desde cliente ubuntu

Tags: linux, formularios

En mi empresa hay un servidor en Linux Arch con una base de datos. A ese servidor se conecta un cliente y crea estadísticas y gráficos con los datos recogidos. Recientemente me pidieron que clonara el cliente para poder acceder al servidor desde dos clientes. Se debe acceder a través del mismo usuario/contraseña en ambos clientes.
Los clientes se loguean, y acceden a un formulario dividido en varias páginas donde recopilan datos y crean los gráficos.
Para loguearse acceden a una base de datos local en localhost y para recopilar datos acceden a la base de datos del servidor.
El cliente original accede a todo sin problemas, pero el otro cliente, tras loguearse sin problemas, cuando intenta acceder al servidor para ir cogiendo los datos que se van seleccionando en varias páginas de un formulario, no puede acceder y no muestra las posibles opciones.
He revisado por iptables si se había creado en el servidor alguna restricción a la ip del cliente clon pero no aparece ninguna. En un php del servidor con nombre phpmyadmin había unos rangos de ip admitidos. Cambié la ip, que iba por dhcp a fija para que estuviera dentro de uno de los rangos, pero no funciona.
He buscado en el servidor algún php que habilitara al cliente original para crearlo también para el cliente clon, pero no he encontrado nada.
He leído que podía haber blacklist y/o whitelist que pudieran contener ip's habilitadas o restringidas y he buscado las de los clientes para ver si ahí se había habilitado al cliente original o se había restringido al clon, pero, o no están, o no las encuentro.

Comment: Has probado a utilizar el puerto 23 (Telnet) para abrir la comunicación mediante ssh? También puedes intentar usar herramientas como PuTTY para establecer la comunicación ssh. Este tipo de software son muy intuitivos de configurar y facilitan la tarea.

Comment: No, no se me había ocurrido porque el cliente que cloné accede bien por el puerto habilitado (creo que 24) y por ello no se me ocurrió, pero recojo la sugerencia y lo probaré. Muchas gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Ese mensaje de `connection refused` suena a que el puerto no está abierto, por lo menos desde el punto donde estás tratando de establecer la conexión. Puedes hacer telnet al puerto 24 desde ese mismo host? `telnet el-servidor 24`. Si eso falla para conectar, entonces el problema no es de ssh.

Comment: Efectivamente, el puerto no está abierto. No se me ocurrió probar el ssh con el cliente original porque funciona correctamente. Lo he probado y el error es el mismo, por lo que no es un problema de puerto, ni de ssh, creo. El compañero que lo utiliza dijo que no se conecta bien y me sugirieron hacer primero un ping y luego comprobar el ssh. He comprobado otras cosas y creo que el problema es distinto de lo que pensaba, así que voy a reescribirlo. Lamento los vaivenes.

Answer (score 1):

Puede que tengas que generar un nuevo par de claves ssh para el ordenador clonado, o si no, volver a hacer las conexiones ssh desde el principio borrando las claves del servidor

En el servidor:

```sh
/bin/rm -v /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
# borra todas las claves antiguas, si están en la ruta por defecto
```

```sh
dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
# Reconfigura openssh server para crear las claves de host

systemctl restart ssh
# para reiniciar el servicio ssh
```

Y en los clientes:

```sh
ssh-keygen -R <IPServidor>
# actualiza el fichero /.ssh/known_hosts

ssh <IPServidor>
# para la conxión
```